# Debounce/delay TinyMCE Blazor

Tags: tinymce

How do I setup a debounce/delay to prevent Blazor updating model on every keystroke?

I have looked through TinyMCE docs but that feature seems to be deprecated. Somehow it seems deprecating something this important is unlikely, what's more likely is that I can't find it.

My current TinyMCE config

```
new Dictionary<string, object>{
        {"menubar", false },
       {"toolbar", "undo redo styleselect forecolor bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify outdent indent" },
        {"toolbar_location", "top" },
        {"toolbar_mode", "scrolling" },
        {"statusbar",false },
        {"placeholder", "Type here..."},
        { "content_style", "body { margin: 0px 3px 0px 13px; line-height:0.9; }  "},
        { "height", "110"}
      }
```

Editor call

`<TinyMCE.Blazor.Editor @bind-Value=Value ScriptSrc="/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" Conf="@config" Inline="@Inline" />`

Comment: You're not showing all the required code.  How are you implementing the control in Blazor?

Comment: I am not doing it myself, It's provided by tinymce. See the edit.

Comment: I see.  I used the ASP.NET version of TinyMCE and liked it.  But I, too, wouldn't want an update every single time I press a key.  Not too bad if you are running on a dev machine, but maybe ugly for someone on the other side of the world.